# difference between metrics for cassandra_columnfamily_* cassandra_table_*

Tags: cassandra, jmx, grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to setup alerts for apache cassandra. using jmx exporter to expose the metrics and prometheus to pull the metrics and grafana will be display the graphs. while looking for the metrics i see it has both cassandra_columnfamily_readlatency and cassandra_table_readlatency. does both of them have any difference. can some one point me to any related documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is the new one. It used to be called columnfamily (from google bigtable paper) but was renamed. To maintain backwards compatibility with older tools the column family alias was created. Its the same metric but in some versions the alias of some of the metrics is missing (a bug) so the table metrics has more.

Use table to future proof app. columnfamily deprecated.